# How are errors (not related to syntax) managed in arduino and in the AVR architecture in general?

Tags: arduino-ide, avr, mathematics, error

I was just curious about how the AVR architecture manages errors that would cause a regular desktop program to crash. I'm talking about logical errors for example math problems that are undefined. Such as division by 0 and getting a square root of a negative number. At first I was expecting that by giving an error to the AVR chip it will just return 0. But I ran this program:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
int x = 0;
int p = 50;
int result;
result = p/x;
Serial.println(result);
result = sqrt(-10);
delay(1000);
Serial.println(result);
delay(10000);
}
```

and got this output:

```
4294967295
0
```

After this I got really confused. Why would the `result` variable take the maximum value of an `unsigned long`? Since I declared an `int` the micro controller must have dedicated 2 bytes of dynamic memory to this variable but apparently it somehow managed to get additional 2 bytes to store the data. Could this mean that the AVR chip can corrupt data in other memory locations while allocating new data for the variable that just was fed a undefined in to it? Okay maybe the AVR chip just sets any mathematical nonsense to 4294967295. But no in the example of getting the square root of -10 we see that the value became 0. Although this is probably a function processed by some library so maybe there is some kind of protection against these errors. Also, I tried to run the program above but with a `byte` variable for the `result` instead of `int`.

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
int x = 0;
int p = 50;
int result;
result = p/x;
Serial.println(result);
result = sqrt(-10);
delay(1000);
Serial.println(result);
delay(10000);
}
```

And the result was the same. So, is there some kind of documentation about error management in AVR since this is important to know while development.

P.S. Everything was run on a real Atmega 328p chip on an arduino nano.

Comment: I think the standard is that it is undefined for integer math. The floating point is according to the IEEE standard and returns a nan, but no exception. Catching an exeption in the Arduino is not possible (I think) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095591/enable-exceptions-in-the-arduino-environment When you find strange things with a byte, please give a full sketch that we can try and tell us which arduino board you use.

Comment: @Jot This is an interesting point but why would a nan be replaced with 4294967295. Apparently they don't have the same binary value. Why did Atmel not include a nan value (that maybe could be disabled through fuses) in their processor architecture. This is a useful troubleshooting feature that is heavily used in all major programming languages.

Comment: @Jot I used an Arduino nano with an Atmega 328p on board.

Comment: An integer can not be a 'nan', that is specified for floating point. Please update your question with board and microcontroller, and perhaps a full sketch.

Comment: I tried to make a sketch myself, and I have different results. Please show your sketch and tell us the results of the sketch that you show. Are you running this in a simulator?

Comment: @Jot No, everything is being run on a real arduino.

Comment: Thank you for the full sketch. I have added an answer. You have run into a very weird compiler bug that causes the 4294967295. Now I understand why my code did not show that number and your code does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is: they are not handled at all.

According to the C and C++ standards, what you are invoking is called
[*undefined behavior*](https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs), meaning anything can happen. In practical
terms, it means that the compiler can do its optimizations *assuming*
you will never invoke undefined behavior, and completely disregard what
could happen if the assumption does not hold. The generated code could
be completely broken, it won't be the compiler's fault.

The AVR architecture cannot do divisions, nor floating point math. Thus
all the errors you have here happen at the software level. Note that
`sqrt(-10)` is *not* an error (it's NaN, which is correctly handled by
the avr-libc), but converting that to an int (which you do when you
assign it to `result`) is an error.

If you really want to know the details of what happens with each of
these errors, there is only one option: you have to disassemble the
executable program and read the assembly listing.

Comment: _"... undefined behavior, meaning anything can happen."_ - It's worth emphasizing that this is completely a C/C++ thing, unrelated to the AVR chips. The exact same warning applies to code running on, say, an Intel i5.

Comment: Also worth noting that while the C++ standard states that the compiler can do *anything*, C++ compilers typically define additional behavior beyond the C++ specification.  For example, Visual Studio's compiler defines the behavior of `x/0` which was undefined in the C++ spec, based on what it knows about the architecture.  This is really useful when you want to do something the spec forbids, but your particular compiler permits, like gcc extensions.

Answer (score 1):

**About the number 4294967295**

To my surprise, the sketch produces indeed the number 4294967295. That is not okay.
It turns out that the compiler knows the numbers and tries to do the math itself (instead of runtime).

At runtime, the `50 / 0` results into a signed integer of -1.
When a byte is used, the `50 / 0` results into 255.
The result of that calculation is a variable with only 1's. That is 0xFFFF for a 16-bits variable. That results into 65535 for a unsigned integer and -1 for a signed integer and 255 for a unsigned byte.

So far, that is okay. It makes sense.

However, when the compiler tries to do the math itself with `50 / 0`, it turns the result into a 32-bit variable of 0xFFFFFFFF. The compiler does not put the math into the binary result, but calls the Serial.println() directly with a 32-bit unsigned long of 0xFFFFFFFF, which is 4294967295.

The reason is not the variable type of the variable '`result`', but the division with '`p/x`'. The compiler thinks it is better to make a 32-bit integer when the math is done with two 16-bit integers.

I think that when the compiler optimizes, the result should be same as a runtime calculation.
There is an interesting discussion below this answer. @EdgarBonet calls the compiler behaviour weird but not a bug.

Below is a test sketch that produces 4294967295 with Arduino 1.8.7 for an Arduino Uno:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  int x = 0;
  int p = 50;
  int result;
  result = p/x;
  Serial.println(result);
  delay(5000);
}
```

The code outputs normal results when 'x' or 'p' is calculated, for example the result from a function, or when one of the three variables is made volatile.

Comment: The handling of undefined behavior by the compiler is _never_ a bug because, by definition, whatever the compiler does is acceptable per the language standard.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I think it should do whatever in the same way. In your opinion the compiler can insert code to whistle a tune when dividing by zero? I don't think so. Changing an int to unsigned long is too weird in my opinion.

Comment: Although the compiler may not _deliberately_ do silly things, strange things do happen when you invoke undefined behavior. See for example the beginning of [this blog post](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) (the whole post series is a must-read for any C or C++ programmer). Weird? Yes. Bug? No.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, thanks, interesting to read that. The things they mention are straightforward. What happens here is that runtime a certain function is called, and when the compiler optimizes it, a different (overloaded) function is called. That is one step further into weirdness.

Comment: _"In your opinion the compiler can insert code to whistle a tune when dividing by zero? I don't think so."_ - When you invoke Undefined Behaviour, everything goes, including unexpectedly large variables, tune whistling, or formatting your hard drive. Welcome to the wonderful world of C and C++. It would be interesting though to see if the same "variable promotion" occurs without UB.

Comment: It only happens when x is zero and p is non-zero. When the 4294967295 is printed, the sizeof(result) is still 2.